I am a Filipino working in Japan. Can I visit Taiwan directly from Japan?
I am a Filipino currently in Japan as an overseas worker. Can I visit Taiwan directly from Japan? I am planning to travel from Kansai Airport in Japan to Taiwan and stay there for about 5 days.

As a Philippines passport holder, you do not need a visa for tourism for trips up to 14 days in Taiwan.
You do need a return ticket and proof of accommodations in Taiwan.

(+1) This mentions that the visa exemption for nationals of the Philippines is effective until 31 July 2025
